# Outbound Message MobileConnect

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I am not able to get my NextKeyword message with my outbound message. Below is the screenshot. My understanding is that I will receive the message with FIRST_NAME next keyword automatically after this outbound message. But I am not getting that.

What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When Next Keywords are assigned to message templates, it enables two or more messages to be linked (or chained) together. When a user **replies** to a message with a noun and a next keyword is assigned to that template, then the message will be interpreted with the keyword. This chain can continue for mulitple messages. Once the user reaches the last template in the chain, they will be ejected from the chain. For example, in your scenario:

1. Contact receives outbound message, where the Next Keyword is set to 'FIRST_NAME'
2. Contact replies 'Samantha'
3. Mobile Originated (MO) message is interpreted as 'FIRST_NAME Samantha' and is parsed by a message template that has the keyword 'FIRST_NAME'.

So in your second message template (which uses the FIRST_NAME keyword), if you want to capture the users' mobile number and first name in a Data Extension and respond with a message, your message template could look like this:

```js
%%[InsertData("Your DE Name", "mobile", MOBILE_NUMBER, "response", [MSG(0).NOUNS], "created", SystemDateToLocalDate(Now()))]%%
Thanks for submitting your first name!
```